# How to correctly use QUERY_STRING in ISAPI rewrite?

Tags: asp.net, regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having a difficult time with this and hope you guys can help.

Using Helicon ISAPI Rewrite version 3.1.0.104 on our IIS server.  I edit the http.conf file and have tried everything and still fail.

This is what I am trying to do:

Redirect this url:
https://www.domain.com/switch-by-version?version=2.8.5.2594

to:
https://test.domain.com/load/load.aspx?tver=2.8.5.2594

The version number at the end from the source url will change, and I need the target url to have the same version number at the end of its url as the example above shows.

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^version=(\d\d?)\.(\d\d?)\.(\d\d?)\.(.*)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^/switch-by-version(.*)$ https://test.domain.com/load/load.aspx?tver=%1 [R=307,NC,L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: You going to respond?

Comment: Thank you Walf!  Yes, this is correct!  Sorry, I was at Amazon's reInvent and wasn't checking anything.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's running in the equivalent context of an `.htaccess`, then the rule shouldn't start with a `/`. Here's a simpler version:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^version=(\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:\..+)?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^switch-by-version/?$ https://test.domain.com/load/load.aspx?tver=%1 [R=307,NC,L]
```